# В Android Studio "Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение"

Tags: android-studio

Вечер добрый.
Скачал Android Studio,но у меня возникла проблема, дело в том, что при сборке или просто даже при запуске пишет что "Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение".
Я никак не могу это исправить , помогите пожалуйста!
Ещё у меня процессор AMD и не могу поставить драйвер Гипервизора.

Answer (score 2):

В моём случае нужно было отключить мобильный хот-спот и это сработало

Answer (score 1):

Я Решил эту проблемму просто перезагрузив компьютер... Другие способы не помогли(Invalidate cache, rebuild project)